# Database values are not showing inside the table while using Ajax in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to display the database values inside the table using Ajax in Rails.bou i got the following error.

```
Error:



 Template is missing  
Missing template users/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Site/demo2/app/views"
```

I also added the `search.html.erb` i removed the error but got the blank page.
Please check my below codes.

## views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user ,:url => {:action => "search" }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
       <%= f.text_field :receipt,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"user number",:onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div id="search-output-table">
   <%= render partial: "search_output_table", locales: {user: @user} %>
</div>
```

## controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user=User.new
    end
    def search
        @user = User.find_by_receipt(params[:user][:receipt])
    end
end
```

## views/users/_search.js.erb

```
$("#search-output-table").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(partial: "search_output_table") ) %>");
```

## views/users/_search_output_table.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Email</th>
    <th>User Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @user.name %></td>
    <td><%= @user.email %></td>
    <td><%= @user.receipt %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also want remove onchange event and as soon as the value will fill inside text field the action will execute without reload the page as well as the table value will display(initially the table should remain disable/hide).Please help me to resolve this error and add this new scenario.

Comment: You are getting the error because the search action in the users controller expects a template to render.  When you added the template `search.html.erb` the error goes away.  You would have to show us the template to help with why it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on request to *UsersController#search* Rails will by default render *app/views/users/search.html.erb*, which I assume is empty.

You probably just need to rename *views/users/_search.js.erb* to *views/users/search.js.erb* and add following to the controller

```
def search
  @user = User.find_by_receipt(params[:user][:receipt])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Also make sure you're passing in *@user* to the *search_output_table* template. Like this

```
render partial: 'search_output_table', locals: {user: @user}
```

And in 'search_output_table' you should use just *user* instead of *@user*.

Comment: ,Hi Misha,No I did as per you again the blank page is coming.

Comment: @rajat_474 I've updated the answer. And are there any errors in logs or in browser console?

Comment: Misha,I did as per you but got the following error.

Error:->

undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x14750a0>:0x15c6150>

Comment: @rajat_474 and you set locals?

Comment: Yes I just changed inside _search_output_table.html.erb file from @user->user.

Comment: @rajat_474 I'm asking if you set 'locals' when rendering, as I described above

Comment: Yes Misha,I have also set locals as you described above.

Comment: Well, not sure what the problem is. It should work if you spend some time debugging your code and  adjust my answer to your situation.